# how to Installation software using tar.bz2 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: installation, package, ubuntu-16.04, sublimetext, tar

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to install third party software like **Sublime text editor** and **Visual Studio Code**, Some websites provide **.deb** files which can be installed easily  but some provide **.tar.bz2** files

please tell me the procedure to install these files or at least how to install **sublime text editor** [image: content of tar.bz2]

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).

Comment: There are [instructions for how to install Sublime on Ubuntu](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html) available directly from the Sublime website.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm assuming you meant .bz2 not .bzz**

1.Open terminal.

2.cd to the directory having the .tar.bz2.

3.extract the file using `tar xvjf FILENAME.tar.bz2`

4.`./configure`

5.`make`

6.`sudo make install`

Comment: Sublime's commercial and doesn't come with source, so extracting the tarball gives you an already created application folder.